# Поменять цвет у лейбла в table view

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть вот такой экран:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
struct Video {
    var image: UIImage
    var title: String
}

class VideoCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoTitleLabel: UILabel!

    func setVideo(video: Video) {
        videoImageView.image = video.image
        videoTitleLabel.text = video.title
    }
}


class VideoListScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var videos: [Video] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        videos = createArray()
    }


    func createArray() -> [Video] {

        let video1 = Video(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "beginner-first-app"), title: "Your First App")
        let video2 = Video(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dev-setup"), title: "My Dev Setup")
        let video3 = Video(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "int-overview"), title: "iOS Interview")
        let video4 = Video(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ss-delegates"), title: "Buttons in TableViews")
        let video5 = Video(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ss-uipickerview-card"), title: "UIPickerView Tutorial")
        let video6 = Video(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "vlog-4"), title: "Day in the Life")

        return [video1, video2, video3, video4, video5, video6]
    }
}


extension VideoListScreen: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let video = videos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell") as! VideoCell
        cell.setVideo(video: video)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Я хочу поменять цвет шрифта у лейбла, но у меня не получается. Пыталась сделать в методе `cellForRowAt`
Так как он находится в `VideoCell`, а не в контроллере, подскажите как сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в методе cellForRowAt `cell.videoTitleLabel.textColor = .red`

Comment: Извиняюсь, описалась. У меня закрасился весь лейб, а мне нужно поменять цвет шрифта у лейбла

Comment: @Yana исправил ответ